# Finding a sensible range

Tags: r, math, statistics

I'm struggling with this now for a few days. This is now the 3rd question at stackoverflow about the same topic, hope this time my question is better defined.

My data are distributed like this: (histogram)

[image: Histogram of the true data]

The x-axis correspond to the range of probabilities: from 0 to 1.

I want to assign states from state 1 to state 10 sensibly to the probability range.

This is what I have got:

```
Interval <- round(quantile(datag, c(seq(0,1,by=0.10))),3)
```

output:

```
   0%   10%   20%   30%   40%   50%   60%   70%   80%   90%  100% 
 0.000 0.008 0.015 0.024 0.036 0.054 0.080 0.124 0.209 0.397 1.000
```

Assign states from 0 to 10:

```
States <- data.frame(datag, State=findInterval(datag, Interval))

head(States)
```

Output: States

```
Probability      State
0.20585012         8
0.21202839         9
0.07087725         6
0.7109513         10
0.9641807         10
```

The problem is this: As you can see above, I have already state 9 for probability 0.2120 and state 10 for > 0.710. I would be happy with something like prob=0.2120 state 4 and prob=0.710 state 7 and prob=0.96 = state 10.

So how to assign states more uniformly?

To replicate the datag:

```
datag <- data.frame(Probability=rgamma(10000, shape=0.6, rate=4.8, scale=1/4.8))
```

EDIT:
@Roman:

```
datag <- subset(datag, Probability<=1)
```

EDIT: @Simon

Yes, I'm aware of "cut":

```
table(cut(datag, breaks = c(seq(0,0.8,by=0.1))))
```

Output:

```
(0,0.1] (0.1,0.2] (0.2,0.3] (0.3,0.4] (0.4,0.5] (0.5,0.6] (0.6,0.7] (0.7,0.8] 
125545     26625     12795      8126      5556      4108      3227      2606
```

How would one define the breaks? I after the intervals (breaks themselfs) so I can assign the states corresponding to the interval the probability falls in.

Comment: As I understand your problem, `quantile` divides your data into subsets of roughly equal content, `cut` divides your data into subsets of equal length.

Comment: @Simon. Thanks. I have posted EDIT.

Comment: If you could provide a reproducible example and expected result, it would go a long way.

Comment: @Roman. The data are gamma distributed with the parameters as posted above. Now the datag goes from 0 to 1. Correction posted.

Comment: If you don't use `table` after `cut`, you get into which bin each observation falls. Is this what you're after?

Comment: @Roman. You mean this: levels(cut(datag,10)). Possibly. I thought there is other better way how to approach this problem. Thanks.

Comment: This question seems to be a [cross post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/66824/27403) with CV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've basically got the answer in your OP! Don't take this the wrong way, but I think you need to spend some more time reading the documentation for `?cut`! If you set `labels = FALSE` in `cut` you get the integer codes that each break corresponds to.

```
#  Set a seed for true reproducibility!
set.seed(1)
datag <- data.frame(Probability=rgamma(10000, shape=0.6, rate=4.8, scale=1/4.8))
Int <- cut( datag$Probability , breaks = seq(0 , 1 , by = 0.1 ) , lab = FALSE )
head( cbind( Prob = datag$Probability , Int ) )
            Prob Int
[1,] 0.031860645   1
[2,] 0.455054687   5
[3,] 0.134175238   2
[4,] 0.058957301   1
[5,] 0.855493999   9
[6,] 0.009144936   1
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran

```
datag <- data.frame(Probability=rgamma(10000, shape=0.6, rate=4.8, scale=1/4.8))
datag <- subset(datag, Probability<=1)
```

the first one gives a warning which apparently you ignored, but onward:

And if these are supposed to be probabilities, the second step shouldn't be needed. But onward

You used quantiles; datag is not uniform at all, so you got what you got. If you want to divide datag differently you can use `cut`. E.g, for 10 classes, evenly spaced:

```
datagcut <- cut(datag$Probability, 10)
table(datagcut)
```

but then the first class has many cases and the last very few. You can define your own cuts if you like (see ?cut).

Comment: Thanks, yes Indeed the "cut" solution has been offered to me at SO, and it works for me.